# Get a proper way to design the checkbox without being followed by a label tag

Tags: html, css, asp.net, checkbox

I use some CSS to redesign my checkboxes in ASP.NET:

```css
input[type=checkbox] { 
  display: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox]:not([disabled]) + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
  position: relative!important;
  padding-right: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arial' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  content: "O";
  color: #333;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
  content: "X";
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"><label for="myCheckbox">Click</label>
```

This works as long as I set the `Text` property of my ASP checkbox to something that is neither `null` nor `String.Empty`. When I don't set it or set it to an empty string, the produced HTML will not contain the followed `label` tag, thus my CSS will not work.

Is there a way to design the checkbox without a following label tag?

[JSBIN Example (Preview)](http://jsbin.com/rimaconoja/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Can't you just do a check in your C# like so?
`MyString = MyString == string.empty || MyString == null ? ' ' : MyString;`
And then use the non-breaking space character as the replacement, as it'll no longer consider the string to be empty. That's Alt + 0160

Comment: Try  using `asp:Label` and the `AssociatedControlID` property to explicitly display a `<label>` tag. The way the ASP.net checkbox text attribute makes sense to me, if I have left the `text` attribute empty I don't want my page spammed with empty label tags.

Comment: Could you post your C# and the ASPX of your Gridview to have an idea of how are you filling the control?

Comment: The `GridView` takes a smaller part here and simply explains that I generate those `CheckBox` columns with an `ItemTemplate`. All my cells have no `Text` on their `CheckBox`es, so I already set `Text=" "` to solve this issue, but it's ugly and produces an empty `label` tag in the HTML output, I don't like.

Comment: I changed my question a bit, as solving the ASP behavior would be easy but dirty (setting `Text` to " ")

Comment: You should/could still use/insert the text in the label and then restyle the font color to transparent or else, this text can be usefull for old browsers or other tools reading the page :)

Comment: What is your use case? It looks like tic-tac-toe to me, if that is the case there may be easier ways to go about this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get your CSS to work, it would be much easier to modify the CSS than trying to get ASP to play nice. Here's a working version based off the inputs instead of the wonky labels.

```css
input[type=checkbox] { 
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: 0
}
input[type=checkbox]:after {
  padding-right: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arial' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  content: "O";
  color: #333;
  display:block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "X";
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="x$cb1" checked="checked"></input><label for="cb1"></label>
  <br />
  <input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="x$cb2" checked="checked"><!-- not visible -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I was not facing the label-issue I tried this and failed, because the initial checkbox was still visible or everything was hidden, because I was using `display: none` on the `checkbox`. `appearance` did the trick! Unfortunately, it's not supported by IE and Opera.

Comment: My bad, the new Opera masters it, The - still popular - Opera 12 I'd like to support probably not (can't check right now), IE seems to show the classic checkbox, at least. Not bad.

Comment: -webkit-appearance: is supported in the mobile version of IE11 -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn793580(v=vs.85).aspx, but you are correct, the solution wouldn't work well there. *Shakes fist in the direction of Redmond*

It looks like Opera 12 only has a .15% global use rate, not sure they are worth the trouble.

Comment: Well, some customers are using Opera 12. But it shows simple checkboxes instead of nothing in your solution. Probably using your solution when there comes nothing better.

Comment: So I think you deserve the bounty and the answered question. Even when appearance has been dropped from the CSS3 specification. The nice think on this solution is, it falls back to simple checkbox on browsers that don't support this, at least. So I decided to keep my label solution I already had, but implemented your solution for the css class "labelless". This class is set on the item css class of my checkbox column in my grid. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

So, I wasn't able to get it working with *just* an checkbox input because you can't apply pseudo elements to inputs.  But this solution doesn't rely on any JS and would give you complete stylistic control over what the checkbox should look like, even allowing you to set a disabled state on the input should you need it:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

label i:before {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  content: "O";
  color: #333;
}

label input:checked + i:before {
  content: "X";
  color: #ffa500;  
}

label input[disabled] + i:before {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <i></i>
</label>
```

The label doesn't require a for attribute since it's wrapping the input, and will act as the `click` handler for you. I needed the `<i>` element, because there's no way for me to tell if a child `<input>` is `:checked`.

Hopefully this helps, not sure if it'll work if the `<i>` element is empty, but you could always add a `&nbsp;` inside and set the `font-size` to 0.

Comment: I'm working with ASP.NET controls (see my tags), and it adds a label for me when I set the Text to one space. So I can do what you did and I already do that. But it's dirty.

Comment: It is dirty, but that's what you're left with when trying to achieve custom form elements. My solution works across most browsers, but the better solution is to use `appearance: none` solution mentioned elsewhere and claim "progressive enhancement" for unsupported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is way to design the checkbox without an external tag. Because you can't semantically apply :after or :before pseudo elements on non container elements, the exception to this rule is chrome browser where we can apply :after and :before to non container elements. If you want to run your web application in chrome browser please follow the below code.

```css
input[type=checkbox] { 
  visibility: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox]:before {
  position: relative !important;
  padding-right: 3px;
  top: 1px;
  font-family: 'Arial' !important;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  content: "O";
  color: #333;
  visibility: visible;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked:before {
  content: "X";
  color: #ffa500;
}
```

```html
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="x$cb1" checked="checked"></input>   
<label for="cb1"></label>
<br />
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" name="x$cb2" checked="checked"><!-- not  visible -->
```

Please have a look at the snippet the way the code works is by using `visibility: hidden` on the parent and then `visibility: visible` on the child :before pseudo element. Note: this will not work on firefox browser.

Comment: Sadly, we need to support all browsers.

Comment: @modiX I'm editing the answer now to report that only works in some browsers and I'll try to keep it updates as compatibility increase!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use checkbox
just try

```
//HTML
<span class="my-custom-checkbox">
    <i class="fa fa-check" style="visibility:hidden"></i>
</span>

//CSS

.my-custom-checkbox{
    border:1px solid #555;
    border-radias:4px;
    height:8px;
    width:8px;
}
.my-custom-checkbox>i{
    color:#555;
}

// jQuery code

$(".my-custom-checkbox").click(function(event){
    var selector=$(this).find("i.fa");

    if(selector.css("visibility")=="hidden"){
        selector.css("visibility","visible");
    }
    else{
        selector.css("visibility","hidden");
    }
});
```

This type of straightgy will give you freedom to implement your need with low cost of effort.