# Reusable React checkbox component with image without ID

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to make a reusable React component for a checkbox.

Now, I know what a standard image-replacement for a checkbox looks like, so here it is in my React project:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Checkbox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="thing" value="valuable" id="thing"/><label for="thing"></label> {this.props.text}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkbox;
```

And here's the general CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  background: url("checked.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: url("unchecked.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Now, because this is React, I want to be able to reuse this component.  But, I can't reuse an ID.  What should I do to make a checkbox with an image replacing the native checkbox?  Is there a way to do this without this "label" method?  **I'd prefer to not use a random number as the ID, or something along those lines.**

Comment: @AndrewLi As far as I can tell, the hack doesn't work without an ID, because the label attaches itself to the input via the ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate unique IDs for form labels in React?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420835/how-to-generate-unique-ids-for-form-labels-in-react)

Comment: I don't suspect there's another way to do it. IDs have to be unique and you'll have to generate something unique every time for the ID or else you can't really have labels.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLi. I understand how to make unique IDs. I'd like to avoid that method if possible, whether it be to not use the "label" method, or some other way.

Comment: @AndrewLi is there another way to use an image for a checkbox besides this method that I didn't find?

Comment: So I understand you're trying to have a custom image for the checkbox?

Comment: @AndrewLi yes, that's the root of the problem.

Comment: Well, I'm not a CSS expert. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31442011/5647260) which does not have the need for an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the id as a prop to the component when you instantiate it.

`<Checkbox id="whatever" value={state.valueOrWhatever} text="Change The Value!" />`

in your component (note `for` in JSX is `htmlFor`):

`<input type="checkbox" name={this.props.id} value={this.props.value} id={this.props.id} />
<label htmlFor={this.props.id}></label> {this.props.text}`

Answer (score 0):

my way to do this is usually to do something like this:

```
<div className="checkbox">
   <label><input type="checkbox" value="valuable" /> <span>{this.props.text}</span></label>
</div>
```